# MVC Expose class and assembly name in View, what are the risks?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, reflection

I have view model class: DummyClass.cs in project: ViewDataModels.
Running MVC Razor app is named MyWebApp. In this web app I have View /Home/Index.cshtml and form with hidden field where is line of code that exposes DummyClass AssemblyQulifiedName

```
'@typeof(DummyClass).AssemblyQualifiedName'
```

results in

```
ViewDataModels.DummyClass, ViewDataModels, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

so in post I can through reflexion get class type that represens model.
What are the risks here? Are there any work arounds? For ex.: two way hash of the string?

Comment: Maybe I'm going off-topic here, but this sounds like a strange wish? In MVC the Controller Action should specify which type to pass to it: `public ActionResult DoSomething(DummyClass myData)`, and then you just (have to) make sure that the View / the Form adheres to that. That is the basic premise of MVC, with model binding and validation that come with it for free.

Comment: Yes MVC concept makes is straightforward and setting it as model of this view could solve this. But in this scenario is name of class can have different values, so cleaner solution could be enum or base class, but I'm kinda unconfortable with enum to class mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No risks. 
You cannot hide your code. There are so many good tools out there that help you disassemble dlls that you really can't obfuscate anything anymore.

Obfuscating your code only deters the most casual of people. As the video game industry leaned a long time ago, no code is safe from cracking.